# Span in upper div interferes with span lower div

Tags: css

I have a form with a set of divs that act as rows in a table.
Each row div has a set subordinate divs
Outer
...Left
...Right
.....Top
.....Bottom

A span in the Top div interferes with a span in the Bottom div.
==> the span in the Top div causes the span in the bottom div
to be displaced to the right.  When I turn off "float:left" for the Top div span, the problem goes away.

Image below shows the HTML, related CSS and results.

[image: Snapshots of HTML, CSS, and Results]

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of just a picture so we can debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a clear:left on your ListRowBottomDiv class like this:

```
.ListRowBottomDiv {
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.